# How to replace the value of array using separate method?

Tags: java, arrays

Here in array I insert 0 value in all array index, now I want to check if any array index is equal to 0, then replace the value 0 by value 1, but only one time. for example at the beginning it will find `index [0]==0` then replace it by 1 then stop the execution. if `index[0]==1`, then loop need to find next index where `value==0` and replace that value 0 with 1.

```
public class test {
    static int roomArray[] = new int[10];
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            roomArray[i] = 0;
            System.out.println(roomArray[i]);
        }
        test.book();
    }
    public static void book() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the room you want to book");
        int desiredRoom = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (roomArray[i] == 0) {
                roomArray[desiredRoom] = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to

```
 int desiredRoom= sc.nextInt();
 if(roomArray[desiredRoom]==0){
       roomArray[desiredRoom]= 2;
 }
```

so you are checking and setting the same position

Answer (score 0):

Your code and your requirements to not really match. If you go for

> now i want to check if any array index ==0; then replace the value 0 by value 1, but only one time. for example in the begining it will find index [0]==0 then replace it by 1 then stop the execution. if index[0]==1, then loop need to find next index where value ==0 and replace that value 0 with 1.

then it could be like adding a break or even return

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
  if(roomArray[i]==0){
    roomArray[desiredRoom]= 2;
    break;
  }
}
```

If you want to check only the desired rom, then it is like Scary Wombats answer.